# Visual Flow and Callout

Tags: visual-workflow, callout, dml, invocable-method

I have a small problem with visual flow. I try to execute callout in flow through `@InvocableMethod` but before this callout, I do update a record(standard update action in Visual flow not in apex code(update)), and I got issues:

> "You have uncommitted work pending. Please commit or rollback before
>   calling out"

Yes I know that I can not execute DML before callout but I try to perform my DML(update) in subflow and then execute callout and I got issues too and when trying callout transfer to subflow I got issues too.

1. Can you explain why?
2. Flow and subflow is it different transaction?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this (and best practice for all invocable apex that does callouts is to do the callout in either an `@future` or `Queueable`). This way

- The DML done by the flow (or subflow) + invocable invocation occurs in transaction 1
- The callout is done in transaction 2

Answer (score 0):

Subflows are executed in the same transaction.
To create a new transaction and complete the dml work before the callout, insert a screen or pause node.
The pause node can be configured to resume 0 hours from the current time if you need the flow to continue without human interaction.